# Regular Expression Match Every Occurrence Until Character Except If Preceding Character is a Certain Character

Tags: regex

the following regular expression:

```
[^;].+?(?=;)
```

will match anything until the ';'

```
example: select * from table;select * from tableb;
```

only the select statements will be matched and this is what i want, **BUT** in case i had

`select * from /; tablec ;`

i want the match to be the `select * from /; tablec` i.e. ignoring the semi colon that has a `'/'` before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex like this,

```
[^;](?:\/;|.)+?(?=;)
```

`(?:\/;|.)` this would match `/;` or `.` any character one or more times greedily.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uV7yF6/1)

**or**

Use negative lookbehind.

```
[^;].+?(?=(?<!\/);)
```

Comment: is the second one more efficient or its differ?